# I am one step closer to installing ubuntu, back is grayed out and I was stupid enough to not make a backup

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, backup, bootloader

Ok, so yeah, i've been stupid enough not to make a backup and 1 step closer to installing ubuntu. What I need is that is windows totally safe and not gonna be touched
I made a new partition from windows, and in ubuntu installer I chose "Something else"
Then I chose that partition as an ext4 and mount "/"
Device for bootloader is my hard disk, /dev/sda/, that's what keeps me a little aware.
So I need a quick answer is my windows 7 gonna be touched?

Comment: It would be useful to provide a screenshot of your Partition Editor window, just to be sure.

Comment: I can't click back :(( It's grayed out I now need to choose my country.

Comment: So at which step are you now?

Comment: "Where are you"

Answer (score 0):

Since the system has already formatted the partitions and started copying files, there's not much you can do but wait until it's over and see what you get. If you didn't touch the Windows partition at the partitioning step, you should be fine.

About the boot loader: installing it on the master boot record of your hard drive will not alter your Windows installation, either. The worst that can happen is that if you want to get rid of Ubuntu later, you will have to restore the Windows boot loader (see [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader)).